# ui-router and bookmarkable tabs when using subviews

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui-router in my AngularJS project and I have a route configured so different templates and controllers are used for the same URL.

```
.state('app.communications', {
    url: '/communications',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: function($rootScope, $state, $log) {
        if ($rootScope.hasRole(BUYER_ROLE)) {
            $log.info('Routing to Buyer Communications...');
            $state.go('app.communications.buyer');
        } else if ($rootScope.hasRole(SUPPLIER_ROLE)) {
            $log.info('Routing to Supplier Communications...');
            $state.go('app.communications.supplier');
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        Connection: 'Connection',
        connections: function (Connection) {
            return Connection.query().$promise;
        }
    }
})

.state('app.communications.buyer', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'BuyerConnectionsController',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/buyer_communications.html'
})

.state('app.communications.supplier', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'ConnectionsController',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/communications.html',
    resolve: {
        SampleRequest: 'SampleRequest',
        sampleRequests: function(SampleRequest) {
            return SampleRequest.query().$promise;
        }
    }
})

.state("app.communications.supplier.shares", { url: "/shares" })
.state("app.communications.supplier.requests", { url: "/sample-requests" })
```

This works as I'd like it to. However, it does have one problem. I have a ui-sref="app.communications" in a left nav menu. When I click on it the first time, the view loads just fine. When I click on it a second time, a blank screen loads. I found that adding ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" solves the problem, but it seems strange that I have to do this.

The second problem I encountered is adding bookmarkability to tabs in my 'tpl/communications.html' template. I have the following setup in my controller.

```
$scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Connections', route:'app.communications.supplier', content:'communications.html'},
    { title:'Shares', route:'app.communications.supplier.shares', content:'shares.html'},
    { title:'Sample Requests', route:'app.communications.supplier.requests', content:'sampleRequests.html'}
];

$scope.active = function(route){
    return $state.is(route);
};

$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
        console.log(tab);
    });
});
```

And I'm rendering tabs using ui-bootstrap:

```
<tabset class="tab-container" justified="true">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" ui-sref="{{tab.route}}">
        <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I can click on tabs just fine and the URL changes as expected. However, if I refresh the page (with a URL like /communications/shares) in my address bar, the "$stateChangeSuccess" event gets called twice. The first time, it's for the correct state (app.communications.supplier.shares), but the second time it's for the first tab (app.communications.supplier). I tried many things to try to prevent the second event from happening, but was unsuccessful.

Does anyone know how to make tab bookmarkability work when working with child states like this?

If I don't have child controllers that are delegated to by the parent, everything works fine.

Comment: should be able to set a url param in router `url: '/somePath/:tabname'` also set main state property `abstract:true`